# How to access sx props of year picker inside Material UI's <DatePicker/>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using the `DatePicker` component in Material UI. I want to access the sx props of the year picker section but I don't know how.

What I Tried:

I tried using the `slotProps` and `sx` props to access the sx props of the year picker section but I was not successful.

Expected Result:

I want to be able to access the `sx` props of the year selector section to change the color of the selected year on the blue color background that appears in the image.

[image]

Code:

```
<DatePicker
          defaultValue={dayjs().subtract(1, "month")}
          label="Tarih Başlangıcı"
          onChange={(e: dayjs.Dayjs | null) =>
            setDateStart(e?.format("DD.MM.YYYY"))
          }
          slotProps={{           
            day: {
              sx: {
                "&.MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin.Mui-selected": {
                  bgcolor: "var(--c1)",
                },                
              },
            },
          }}
          sx={{
            ".MuiInputBase-root": {
              borderRadius: 25,
            },
            ".MuiButtonBase-root": {
              color: "var(--c1)",
            },
            ".Mui-focused": {
              ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { borderColor: "var(--c1)" },
              "&.MuiInputLabel-formControl": { color: "var(--c1)" },
            },
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to target the selected year in the year picker:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DemoContainer } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DemoContainer components={["DatePicker"]}>
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic date picker"
          slotProps={{
            layout: {
              sx: {
                "& .MuiPickersYear-yearButton.Mui-selected": {
                  backgroundColor: "purple",
                },
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      </DemoContainer>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit DatePicker custom year picker]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I had to add !important why didn't it work without adding !important?

Comment: Please share a code sandbox reproducing your problem with needing `!important`. I didn't use it in my example and it worked fine.